# How to hide the ruler when look element in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

The new chrome has ruler when look an element, I want to hide it. Is there any setting can help?

Answer (score 17):

Chrome team introduced an option in the code on Nov 8 http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/133885

It's not yet present

**update:** 
It's finally here, "show rulers" checkbox under Developer Tools->Settings->General Tab->Elements.

My Chrome version is 24.0.1312.52 m

Comment: Just for people like me, the "Settings" in the Developer Tools is the **gear-wheel** in the lower left corner (Chrome 27+) :)

Comment: Now this is three dots in the upper right of the dev tools.

Comment: I found I had to close out of Dev Tools and re-open them after toggling the preference in order for it to take effect.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using a recent version of Chrome this is how to find it.

Developer tools > Settings (under more options menu) > Preferences > Elements > Show rules (last option)

Answer (score 2):

Right-click anywhere on the screen, "Inspect Element", gear-wheel in the lower left (Windows) or in the lower right (Mac), "General" tab, scroll down at the bottom "Show Rulers". Check it on/off to liking.